# ComboBox takes in String values. How can I use a loop to insert 1-10 (1 to 10) in a ComboBox?

Tags: java

Just want to insert 1-10 values in a ComboBox. How to convert int i to string values?

```
    for(int i=1;i<11;i++){

        quantityCombo.addItem(i); //Not accepting int values
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Use Generics and Try Like this....
     JComboBox<Integer>  quantityCombo= new JComboBox<Integer>();

        // add items to the combo box
         for(int i=1;i<11;i++){

                quantityCombo.addItem(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.toString(i)` to convert your integer into a String. 
Your code will look like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<11;i++){
    quantityCombo.addItem(Integer.toString(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

You are looking for Integer.parseInt(int), or toString(int). Plenty of choices.

And the real way of solving this is to give a **model** to the combo box. 
You don't want to add its "items" one by one; you create a data structure (for example an array) that you pass as one thing; see the official [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Finally: ComboBoxes accept a **type** parameter; so as khaja suggested, you can also create a ComboBox that will display only Integer entries.
And when an Integer is expected, the compiler will do the work for your, and

```
quantityCombo.addItem(i);
```

works out of the box - because the compiler does **auto-boxing** to create an Integer object from the provided int value.